# MSDeploy - Can not deploy using the batch file generated by msbuild

Tags: msbuild, nant, msdeploy

With visual studio 2012 set up projects has been discontinued. I was finding a way to automatically do a web deploy using team city and I stumbled across this fantastic article

http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

I was able to create a package for my website(LogIn) using msbuild, which created following artifacts

```
PackageTmp
Login.deploy.cmd
Login.deploy-readme.txt
Login.SetParameters.xml
Login.SourceManifest.xml
Login.zip
```

What I wanted to do next is, after doing some xml transform using Nant inbuilt peek functionality, I simply want to invoke the Login.deploy.cmd through Nant. To test this batch file, I ran this file with following parameter

> login.deploy.cmd /T

which generated following out put

```
=========================================================
SetParameters from:
"C:\Soft\Nant\nant-0.92\bin\LogIn\LogIn\obj\Debug\Package\Login.SetParameters.xm
l"
You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString
or other deploy parameters in the above file.
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C
:\Soft\Nant\nant-0.92\bin\LogIn\LogIn\obj\Debug\Package\Login.zip' -dest:auto,in
cludeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentE
xtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\Soft\Nant\nant-0.92
\bin\LogIn\LogIn\obj\Debug\Package\Login.SetParameters.xml"  -whatif
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Creating application (Default Web Site/Login_deploy)
Info: Adding virtual path (Default Web Site/Login_deploy)
Info: Adding directory (Default Web Site/Login_deploy).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\About.aspx).
Info: Adding directory (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account\ChangePassword.aspx).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account\ChangePasswordSuccess.a
spx).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account\Login.aspx).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account\Register.aspx).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Account\Web.config).
Info: Adding directory (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\bin).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\bin\LogIn.dll).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\bin\LogIn.pdb).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Default.aspx).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Global.asax).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Login.aspx).
Info: Adding directory (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Scripts).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Scripts\jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js).

Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Scripts\jquery-1.4.1.js).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Scripts\jquery-1.4.1.min.js).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Site.Master).
Info: Adding directory (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Styles).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Styles\Site.css).
Info: Adding file (Default Web Site/Login_deploy\Web.config).
Info: Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/Login_deploy)
Info: Adding ACL's for path (Default Web Site/Login_deploy)
Total changes: 27 (26 added, 0 deleted, 1 updated, 0 parameters changed, 549895
bytes copied)
```

The logs says it has created a virtual directory by name Login_deploy, but when I check it from inet manager, I do not see any virtual directory with this name.

I am little bit confused here. Any suggestions welcome.

Edit

I also tried to invoked the msdelpoy exe manually using the following command line parameter

```
msdeploy.exe 
-source:package=’Login.zip‘ 
-dest:auto 
-verb:sync 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-allowUntrusted 
-retryAttempts=2 
-setParam:’IIS Web Application Name’=’TargetWebApp‘
```

which gave following error

```
Error: Unrecognized argument 'Web'. All arguments must begin with "-".
Error count: 1.
```

Comment: im not familiar with web deployment but regarding your manually invoked msdeploy command: have you tried to replace ’(apostrophe) with '(quote) or "(double quote)? those are actually different characters

Comment: If you are automating publish you should not need the .cmd file. I have blogged about how to automate publishing at http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/CommandLineWebProjectPublishing.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
login.deploy.cmd /Y
```

Tthe /T switch is for testing, and the /Y switch will actually install the package.